# Create Spark Session to Hive from client (windows)

Tags: windows, hadoop, apache-spark, hive, hadoop-yarn

I'm attempting to create a Spark Session on my local machine (Windows - Intellij) with Hive support using the master of "Yarn" which is hosted on another server.

Currently, I'm compiling my package, dropping it on an edge-node and submitting it via spark-submit. It would be a HUGE time saver to debug directly within Intellij.

```
val hive: SparkSession = SparkSession.
builder().
master("yarn"). // How does one redirect this to another server?
enableHiveSupport().
getOrCreate()
```

I'm very new to Spark and definitely still learning. Any help would be truly appreciated.

Thanks!!

Michael

Comment: https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-apache-spark/content/spark-tips-and-tricks-running-spark-windows.html

Comment: Copy all Hadoop conf files from the Edge Node (`core-site.xml` and friends) and also Hive conf file (`hive-site.xml`) to your PC, then set env variable `HADOOP_CONF_DIR` to point to that directory. That's how Spark will know how to communicate with the cluster.

Comment: Samson, thanks for your help. I actually went through that exact tutorial yesterday. I also made sure to setup the environment variable and added the necessary config files from the cluster to the directory. Here is the error that is returned after trying to kick off a spark session.

17/11/07 16:07:29 ERROR SparkContext: Error initializing SparkContext.
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Unable to load YARN support

Comment: Does it work from the command line on your PC i.e.`spark-submit.cmd`? Because the command line scripts initialize a LOT of env variables and properties under the covers.

Comment: Here is the statement:
spark-submit -
-master yarn --class SparkHiveConnection --name CantinTest --executor-memory 2G
--executor-cores 2 --num-executors 2 --queue bi jdbc_test3_2.11-0.1.jar

I yield the following error.

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/jersey/api/client/config/ClientConfig

Comment: Fine. So the Spark release you downloaded misses some "jersey" JARs. Find them on the Edge node and copy them beside the regular Spark JARs. Then iterate with the next missing dependencies... _(you are new to this messy "ecosystem" shit, aren't you ? )_  B-)

Comment: Absolutely, I am.... In fact, this is my first Stack Overflow post. Thanks for bearing with me thus far! I went ahead and added the missing jars.. Looks like it is actually establishing a connection and attempting to have YARN run the app.

INFO Client: Uploading resource file:/C:/Users/michael.cantin/AppData/Local/Temp/spark-5606f3fa-f324-4c5f-a58a-148d80fe7043/__spark_libs__2285
406551181527371.zip -> hdfs://{cluster}/user/Michael.Cantin/.sparkStaging/application_1509585612019_12082/__spark_libs__2285406551181527371.zip

After some time, it seems to timeout and fail.

Comment: Hmmm. Did you test a `spark-shell` interactive session in `local` mode, trying to load some HDFS file in a local DataFrame? Just to check that you can reach the NameNode and DataNodes (and there is no firewall blocking network traffic between your PC and the cluster).